# Error al pasar parámetros a una sentencia preparada en una consulta MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Resulta que yo hacia consultas sql con querry y ahora me entere porque me dijeron que eso es muy inseguro ante ataques de inyeccion sql por lo tanto decidi comenzar a usar mysqli y bueno hice mi primer reemplazo que fue en el login del sitio, pero aunque el codigo parece estar perfecto la pagina no funciona y me tira un error.

Codigo:

```
$sentencia = $con->prepare("SELECT* FROM cuenta WHERE nombre= '?' or email= '?' and pass= '?'"); 
                    $sentencia->bind_param($sentencia, "sss", $nombre_str, $email_str, $pass_str); 
                    $sentencia->execute();
```

Y el error que me da es:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference in xxxx
```

Cualquier otro dato que necesiten no duden en pedírmelo y desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Dejame comentarte que si tienes mas dudas a tu pregunta original debes abrir otro post... ya que tu pregunta original no tiene que ver nada con la respuesta aceptada...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aqui te dejo un ejemplo completo a tu ultima prejunta, para obtener el `id` con un `while`:

```
$sentencia = $con->prepare("SELECT id FROM cuenta WHERE nombre=? or email=? and pass=? "); 
$sentencia->bind_param("sss", $nombre_str, $email_str, $pass_str); 
$sentencia->execute();
$sentencia->store_result();

if($sentencia->num_rows>0)
   $sentencia->bind_result($id);        
   while ($sentencia->fetch()) {
      //Ya podemos trabajar con $id.
      break;
   } $sentencia->close();
 } else { 
    $sentencia->close();
    echo"0 resultado";
 }
```

Comment: Ademas con ese codigo que me diste si coloco otra contraseña que no es la correcta tambien me deja ingresar

Comment: Listo ya esta todo solucionado era que en el bind result puse unas variables mas y en la consulta preparada solo tenia id

Comment: Me alegro que te a sido util, hay que tener mucho cuidado con los parametros, siempre deben concidir respecto a tu consulta.

Answer (score 2):

Estas mezclando los estilos de [orientado a objeto](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php#example-1869) y otra por [procedimiento](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php#example-1870).

Cambia la linea:

```
$sentencia->bind_param($sentencia, "sss", $nombre_str, $email_str, $pass_str);
```

a

```
$sentencia->bind_param("sss", $nombre_str, $email_str, $pass_str);
```

Y no necesitas poner comillas a las variables `?` en tu consulta:

```
$sentencia = $con->prepare("SELECT* FROM cuenta WHERE nombre=? or email=? and pass=? "); 
$sentencia->bind_param("sss", $nombre_str, $email_str, $pass_str); 
$sentencia->execute();
```